# PHP anonymous function before 5.3 - array_walk

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to use PHP array_walk with an anonymous function (before PHP 5.3)? or some workaround..

I'm using array_walk inside a public class method and I don't want to define a PHP function.. I want to do something like:

```
array_walk($array, function($value) {...});
```

If that's not possible is it possible to use a class method instead of a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an array as second parameter, containing the object and the method name as string:

```
class Foo {
    public function a($a) {
         array_walk($a, array($this, 'b')); 
    }
    private function b($v, $k) {
         print $v;
    }
}
    
$f = new Foo();
$f->a(array('foo', 'bar'));
```

prints

```
foobar
```

---

The signature of the `array_walk()` (can be found in the documentation), defines the second argument as [**callback**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback), for which the following description can be found:

> A PHP function is passed by its name as a string. Any built-in or user-defined function can be used, except language constructs such as: `array()`, `echo()`, `empty()`, `eval()`, `exit()`, `isset()`, `list()`, `print()` or `unset()`.
>
> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an `array` containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.
>
> Static class methods can also be passed without instantiating an object of that class by passing the class name instead of an object at index 0.
>
> Apart from common user-defined function, `create_function()` can also be used to create an anonymous callback function. As of PHP 5.3.0 it is possible to also pass a closure to a callback parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`create_function`](http://php.net/create_function).

```
array_walk($array, create_function('&$v, $k', '$v...'));
```

Comment: I totally forgot about this function. +1

Comment: Thanks... That's easier.. in array_walk documentation I couldn't found that example.. but now I realize that it is in "See Also"..  Sometimes after hours and hours of programming our brain start burning =p

Answer (score 2):

It's possible using [`create_function()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php).

Stolen from the manual:

```
<?php
$av = array("the ", "a ", "that ", "this ");
array_walk($av, create_function('&$v,$k', '$v = $v . "mango";'));
print_r($av);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks... That's easier.. in array_walk documentation I couldn't found that example.. but now I realize that it is in "See Also"..  Sometimes after hours and hours of programming our brain start burning =p

Answer (score 1):

To answer the second portion (the first has been answered well enough I think, although I never really liked `create_function`):

> If that's not possible is it possible to use a class method instead of a function?

Yes, pass `array($instance,'methodname')` or `array('classname','methodname')` for object methods and static methods respectively.